# How to run a loop in ViewDidAppear in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to display a blue and black rectangle alternatively on the launch of the app. I wrote this code. Its compiling fine without any error, but there is no result.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var mybool = true

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


        while(mybool){
            let firstFrame = CGRect(x: 160, y: 240, width: 100, height: 150)
            let firstView = UIView(frame: firstFrame)
            firstView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            view.addSubview(firstView)

            let secondView = UIView(frame: firstFrame)
            secondView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            view.addSubview(secondView)

        }
    }


}
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What stops your while loop?  You seem to be adding an endless number of views at the same location without ever letting the display update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not run an `while` waiting for a property to change on the main thread, ever! It's the thread that your whole UI relies on. The app will look like it has crashed and iOS will kill it sooner or later.

Use Core Animations:

```
weak var loadingView: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let frame = CGRect(x: 160, y: 240, width: 100, height: 150)
    let subview = UIView(frame: frame)
    subview.backgroundColor = .black
    self.view.addSubview(subview)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [.autoreverse, .repeat, .curveEaseInOut], animations: {
        subview.backgroundColor = .blue
    }, completion: nil)

    self.loadingView = subview
}
```

When you want to stop the animation (for example, when loading has finished) :

```
func stopAnimation() {
    loadingView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
}
```